# How to make a summed row into a column

Tags: python, pandas

I do not know how to word this properly but I have a script that takes the sum of each column and places under it. So a row called "total". I instead want this "total" to be a column  not a row. The values are correct but the format it is in now is not.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
headers = [*pd.read_csv("filename",sep='\t', nrows =1)]
df = pd.read_csv("filename",sep='\t', usecols=[c for c in headers if c != 'filenotes'])
df.dropna()
df = df.iloc[:,np.r_[7:20]]
df.loc['Total',:] = df.sum(axis=0)
df.to_csv("filename",sep='\t',index=False)
```

**Edit  for clarification**
My code already does this

```
        a b c
        2 1 3
        2 4 6 
        3 6 9
total   7 11 18
```

I want it to do

```
        a b c total
        2 1 3  7
        2 4 6  11
        3 6 9  18
```

This is because the columns themselves are actually binned data. I have a column denoting the 'bins' and need the total count next to its respective value.

I will be using this to make a bar graph

Comment: `df['total']=df.sum(1)`

Comment: Please acquit yourself on how to ask a question. This may help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This example doesn't make any sense: 11 is not the row-sum of the first row of your data. Could you please recheck and fix your example? You mean '6', right?

Comment: Based on your description it seems you genuinely want to compute column-sums, but then transpose just that row into an extra 'column' called 'Total'. (The fifth revision is still visually confusing: the row-sums 2+1+3 = 6 not 7, and 2+4+6 = 12 not 11.)

Answer (score 1):

You could just change this line:

```
df.loc['Total',:] = df.sum(axis=0)
```

To:

```
df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=0)
```

Them it will assign a new column.

**Edited:**

Try using `tolist`:

```
>>> a = df.sum(0).tolist()
>>> df['Total'] = a + ((len(df) - len(a)) * [np.nan])
>>> df
   a  b  c  Total
0  2  1  3      7
1  2  4  6     11
2  3  6  9     18
>>>
```

Comment: I tried that. When I do that for some reason there are no values in the Total column only blanks

Comment: @Connor It should work now, check the edited part

Comment: 'ValueError: Length of values  does not match length of index. ' The data from the source I downloaded it from isn't perfect. Is there a way to force it to make  'total' to the first column and have the rest proceeding.

Comment: @Connor Edited my answer, try again

Comment: Yes! I was about to abandon this and just make a separate dataframe to merge a transposed column named "total" too. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df["Total"] = df.sum().values
```

It only works if the dataframe is "square-shaped" (number of columns = number of rows).

Answer (score 0):

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7,8]})



   a  b
0  1  5
1  2  6
2  3  7
3  4  8

df['total']=df.sum(1)



   a  b  total
0  1  5      6
1  2  6      8
2  3  7     10
3  4  8     12
```

Comment: My script already does this. If it isn't clear what I am trying to do is turn this total row into a column with the same values. So a column named total with 10 in row 1 and 26 in row 2.

Comment: using this as an example, kindly post your expected output as a table. visuals can be quite helpful

Comment: @Connor `df.loc['total']=df.sum()` and then `df.T`?

Comment: No not a transpose of the whole dataframe just that one particular total row to make it a column. refresh the page and I added clarification. I have a column denoting the 'bins' and need the total count next to its respective value. sorry for the missunderstanding